# Setting data in multiple nested lists ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, list, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm an intern with very basic knowledge of ASP and C#.
I'm trying to display a list of projects > maps > thememaps in an application I'm working on in ASP.NET MVC. In my third foreach I get an error saying: *"Does not contain a definition for "ThemeMaps" and no extension method "ThemeMaps" accepting a first argument of type could be found".*

I'm confused as to why *vmProject.Maps* does not contain the property *ThemeMaps*. I instantiated that list just like maps. What am I doing wrong?

LayersController.cs

```
            // Create viewmodel object
            var viewModel = new AddLayerToThemeMapViewModel();

            // Create Project list
            viewModel.Projects = new List<AddProject>();

            // Loop over all maps
            List<Project> projects = this.applicationDb.Projects.OrderBy(e => e.Title).ToList();
            foreach (var project in projects)
            {
                // Create map
                var vmProject = new AddProject()
                {
                    ProjectId = project.ProjectID,
                    ProjectTitle = project.Title,
                    Maps = new List<AddLayerMap>(),
                };

                foreach (var map in project.Maps.OrderBy(e => e.Title))
                {
                    // Create map
                    vmProject.Maps.Add(new AddLayerMap()
                    {
                        MapId = map.MapId,
                        MapTitle = map.Title,
                        ThemeMaps = new List<AddLayerMapThemeMap>(),
                    });

                    // Loop over all thememaps in map
                    foreach (var thememap in map.ThemeMaps.OrderBy(e => e.Order))
                    {
                        vmProject.Maps.ThemeMaps.Add(new AddLayerMapThemeMap()
                        {
                            ThemeMapId = thememap.ThemeMapId,
                            ThemeMapTitle = thememap.Title,
                        });
                    }
                }

                // Add map to list
                viewModel.Projects.Add(vmProject);
            }
```

My viewmodel class

```
using Mapgear.MapViewer.Entities;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Mapgear.MapViewer.ViewModels
{
    public class AddLayerToThemeMapViewModel
    {
        public Guid LayerId { get; set; }

        public List<AddProject> Projects { get; set; }
    }

    public class AddProject
    {
        public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }

        public string ProjectTitle { get; set; }

        public List<AddLayerMap> Maps { get; set; }
    }

    public class AddLayerMap
    {
        public Guid MapId { get; set; }

        public string MapTitle { get; set; }

        public List<AddLayerMapThemeMap> ThemeMaps { get; set; }
    }

    public class AddLayerMapThemeMap
    {
        public Guid ThemeMapId { get; set; }

        public string ThemeMapTitle { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I made a scetch before I started on paper, which looks like the following:

- LayerId
- List project

  - ProjectId
  - ProjectTitle
  - List Map

    - MapId
    - MapTitle
    - List ThemeMap

      - ThemeMapId
      - ThemeMapTitle

I know my class names are a bit out of wack, however I din't write them myself. Gonna optimize them after.

PS: This is my first question on StackOverflow!

Comment: ``vmProject.Maps`` is ``List<Maps>``. You might want to call FirstOrDefault() on this before accessing ThemeMaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the code in the second for-each loop a bit. I added a variable for the newly created map and add the thememaps to this created map. Check if it's correct.

```
var newMap = new AddLayerMap()
{
    MapId = map.MapId,
    MapTitle = map.Title,
    ThemeMaps = new List<AddLayerMapThemeMap>(),
};
// Create map
vmProject.Maps.Add(newMap);

// Loop over all thememaps in map
foreach (var thememap in map.ThemeMaps.OrderBy(e => e.Order))
{
    newMap.ThemeMaps.Add(new AddLayerMapThemeMap()
    {
        ThemeMapId = thememap.ThemeMapId,
        ThemeMapTitle = thememap.Title,
    });
}
```

Comment: That worked out great, thank you very much! That I din't see this solution myself. How is this different compared to what I did? Cause I thought it was the same.